# Is there any tool where I can effectively find some examples of a specific sound change in world's languages?

Tags: computational-linguistics, sound-change

For example, I have once read about an example of the sound change g > dʐ. I need it now but I cannot find it. Is there anything like "sound change corpus" where I can effectively find some examples of a specific sound change in world's languages? It is better to be like a corpus where I can input some parameters, like if I write

```
[+stop; +velar] > [+affricate; +postalveolar]
```

then I get results as following:

```
English (xxxx A.D. to xxxx A.D.) click to see details / see reference
German (xxxx A.D. to xxxx A.D.) click to see details / see reference
etc.
```

Another thing which would be good is to be able to check the probability of a certain sound change. It is well known that palatalization is a widely found phenomenon, but we do not know the probability of  [+fricative; +postalveolar] > [+fricative; +velar]. Is there any why to check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a resource named [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/) where you can search for sound changes. Make sure to click through from the sound changes to the sources, it is a large compilation of many different sources and you want to consult the original source before writing a paper on that specific sound change.

Unfortunately, it does not support a feature based approach, you will have to check all possible start or end points (the search works in both directions).

I don't see any sensible method to get to probabilities from that resource.